# Accessing Pi remotely

Tags: ssh

If i have a raspberry Pi embedded to a robot, what's the easiest way to access it remotely?

SSH would be perfect, but is it possible if the Pi isn't connected to the internet?

Comment: *"is it possible if the Pi isn't connected to the internet"* -> If your wifi adapter has an **access point** (AP) or **ad hoc** mode then very likely yes, although this also likely means whatever you are connecting to it with will not be able to use the wifi for internet.   If the adapter *doesn't* have such a mode but what you want to connect it with does, you could do it in reverse although this way round may have slightly more complications in terms of establishing the connection.

Answer (score 3):

`ssh` is not possible without a network connection.

I have a Pi in a similar scenario and I use an HC-06. It is a serial bluetooth module, and it allows me to access the command line via Bluetooth.

You might want to check this [blog post](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/a-cheap-bluetooth-serial-port-for-your-raspberry-pi) out.

Comment: While it's true that `ssh` "is not possible without a network connection", a network connection is not necessarily an *internet* connection, and you can create a local subnet with no internet access and use `ssh` between parties.

Comment: @goldilocks I assumed the OP meant network connection. As the two are sometimes confused on this site. But yes, if he has a network connection with no Internet, then `ssh` would work fine.

Comment: Occasionally we get questions from people who, e.g., want to remote control something somewhere in a field where they can get close enough to use wifi, but there is no wifi internet service in the field or whatever.

Comment: @goldilocks The HC-06's *theoretical* range is 500 meters. (Or at least that's what my packaging said) I can assually get about 100 meters away before it starts to become unreliable.

Comment: @goldilocks Well, I'm so used to trying to forget about the imperial system that I wrote "meters" instead of "feet". I'll edit my comment as soon as I'm able to, it won't allow me to edit it at the moment for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. Get a Raspberry Pi 3 B, as it has onboard WiFi and Bluetooth and has the ability to setup a hotspot. With the RPi3B, you will not need a USB dongle, it's onboard.

Comment: As he already has the Pi suggesting he replace it seems a bit much. You also have not mentioned how to setup any of this.

Comment: @Steve He didn't say what kind of Pi he has.